Bounded increase in probability through conditioning
Let $P$ be some known probability distribution such that $P(A)>0$ and $P(B|A) >0$. Is there a bound which describes how much $P(B | A)$ can blow up compared to $P(B)$, in other words, how much conditioning can increase probability, through properties of the distribution? Consider for example conditioning the standard normal on the event $y \in (0, 0.5)$ where $y$ is the observation vs. conditioning the continuous uniform on the unit interval on the same event. The Gaussian's higher concentration means that the event has smaller probability than under the uniform. Is there a general result about this?

It can increase a lot (by any factor, in fact). For example, suppose $X$ has a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, let $B=\{X\in [0,0.01]\}$, then $\mathbb{P}(B)=0.01$. But now let $A=B$, then $\mathbb{P}(B\mid A)=1$ which is 100 times larger...

Sure, I agree that, in general it can increase unboundedly, but there must be systematic differences between distributions which should be able to be captured formally
